# Pushing elemets into priority queue resolved in Invalid Heap

Tags: priority-queue

I am writing a code for Uniform Cost Search using a priority queue. I came across an error: Invalid Heap after using push function. I also tried to debug the code, but I didn't find the source of this error. Here's my code:

```
class Manager
{
private:
    Parser *p;
    Board* myBoard;
    string algorithm;
    string text;
    unsigned int size;
    stack<Brick> *myStack;
    stack<Brick> *solution;
    stack<Brick> *temp;
    unsigned int trackCost;
    set<pair<int,int>> mySet;

    struct ComparatorGreaterThan {
        bool operator() (const Brick lhs, const Brick rhs) {
            return (lhs.getTrackCostUpToMe() > rhs.getTrackCostUpToMe());
        }
    };
public:
    Manager();
    ~Manager();
    void Start();
    void parseText();
    void presentBoard() const;
    const void checkNeighbours( int i,  int j,const int x,const int y,stack<Brick> *tempStack, const Brick father)const;
    void returnNeighbours(const Brick node, stack<Brick>* tempStack,const Brick father);
    bool DFS(const Brick node,const int depth,const Brick father)const;
    void parseSolution();
    void IDDFS();
    void printSolution()const;
    bool UCS();
};
```

and here's the UCS function:

```
bool Manager::UCS()
{
    priority_queue<Brick,vector<Brick>,ComparatorGreaterThan> myQueue;
    myQueue.push(myBoard->getRoot());
    mySet.insert(myBoard->getRoot().getCoorddinates());//Set is used to know which elements,using the coordiantes, are in the PQ
    while (!myQueue.empty())
    {
        Brick parent = myQueue.top();
        myQueue.pop();
        mySet.erase(parent.getCoorddinates());
        if (parent.getSym() == 'G')//If goal is found
        {
            cout << parent.getTrackCostUpToMe();
            return true;
        }
        stack<Brick> tempStack;//Keeps all the neighbours of current node.
        returnNeighbours(parent, &tempStack,myBoard->getNode(parent.getFatherX(),parent.getFatherY()));//Finds all the neighbours of current node.
        while (!tempStack.empty())
        {
            tempStack.top().setTrackCostUpToMe(parent.getTrackCostUpToMe());//Set the track cost of neighbour.

                if (mySet.find(tempStack.top().getCoorddinates()) == mySet.end())//If we don't have neighrbour in the PQ
                {
                    mySet.insert(tempStack.top().getCoorddinates());
                    myQueue.push(tempStack.top());
                    tempStack.pop();
                }
                else //We have the neighbour in the PQ
                    tempStack.pop();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Solved, the problem was that I forgot to overload operator= correctly.